# Floating point: choose epsilon to prevent zero division?

Tags: c++, floating-point, floating-accuracy

I have simple formula in my C++ program:

```
const double z = x / tan(y);
```

`x` is number from 1000 to 10 * 1000,
`y` any angle.

What is the right way to protect the code from zero division?

I mean, I know what to do if `tan(y)` is near zero (which other formula to use), 
but how to check that `tan(y) ~ 0` — what constant to use for checking:

```
const double tn = tan(y);

if (fabs(tn) < EPS) { 
  z = some other formula;
} else {
   z = x / tn;
}
```

What `EPS` should I take here to prevent float point exception?

Comment: If you program in C++, then please only use the C++ tag. C++ and C are two very different languages.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know, but in this particular case I suppose no difference adherent of what language answer for me. Both answers interesting for me.

Comment: I've voted to close this question since answers will be opinion-based, rather than there being a single definitive answer.   The "right" approach depends on how `x` and `y` are obtained in the first place, and also what will be done with `z` once it is computed.   It's quite possible a set of expressions - or an algorithm - can be reorganised to avoid calculating `z` AT ALL.

Comment: Can you show the "other formula" that you're supposed to use when `tan(y)` is near zero? Otherwise, we're trying to compare `x / tan(y)` with something unknown, so it's hard to advise. The optimal threshold is likely to depend on what that formula is, and what you're trying to compute. BTW, why do you think you need a threshold at all? What goes wrong if you simply compare `y` for equality with `0.0`?

Comment: As long as `x` is nonzero, dividing `x` by `tan(y)` is fine even for `tan(y) == 0`. You get an infinity, which is perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you considered code for your check like: `std::abs(tn) >= std::numeric_limits<decltype(tn)>::min()`? That'd prevent zero division as well as division by any sub-normal value.